# Seeking a program to get full-size screenshots on live websites all from from the terminal

Tags: screenshot

I am looking for a program that simple captures a full-size screenshot of a webpage via a terminal command.

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --window-size=1280,1696 https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)? Just run Headless Chrome (see link).

Comment: Yeah that will work well. I am currently using chrome developer tools to obtain screenshots, but, this seems much better. Thank you Micha.